# Why is my array empty? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, function

I am having a bit of a problem right now. I try using a global array and store information to it in one function and try to use the information inside it in another function, but when I try to access the info, it appears as empty, even though I call the function before accessing the information. Here is an example code:

```
var myArray = [];

functionThatLoops(parameter_Array, parameter2){
    for (item in parameter_Array){
        $.get(URL,
        {
            method: "endPointMethod",
            id: item["ID"]
        }, function(data){
            myArray.push(data)
        });
    }
}

mainFunction(){
    c = 1;
    for (array in AnotherMultiDimensionalArray){
        functionThatLoops(array,c);
    }
    console.log(myArray) //Displays Array with correct number of elements and correct info
    console.log(myArray.length) //Displays 0 and after this array appears to be empty

    for (item in myArray){ //Nothing prints out in this loop, as array appears empty
        console.log(item)
    }
}
```

What could be the problem? It looks like the code that fills the array is executing last...

Comment: Where are you calling `mainFunction()`?

Comment: Is `$.get` ajax call?

Comment: Are you sure it is empty or you think that because there is no call to your function

Comment: `$.get()` returns results asynchronously

Comment: `functionThatLoops()` calls an async ajax, on success result is appended to `myArray`. By the time success method is called, the following 2 `console.log` got executed and so `myArray` is empty ;)

Comment: @PriyeshKumar this is just an example code of what´s happening. In reality, mainFunction is a click event. I used this because the real code itself is really huge, but the only problem is this part right here.

Comment: @PriyeshKumar What can I do to correct this?

Comment: If you are doing the same thing in your real code, then still problem is the same! Do you want to wait for all `$.get()` to get finished before further processing on myArray?

Comment: @PriyeshKumar That is correct, I need to wait for all the $.get() to insert data inside myArray, and then I need to process that data inside it.

Comment: Use `$.when()`, `.apply()`; substitute `$.map()` for `for..in` loop. `functionThatLoops(parameter_Array, parameter2) {
      return $.when.apply($, $.map(parameter_Array, function(item) {
        return $.get(URL, {method:"endPointMethod", id:item["ID"]})
               .then(function(data) {myArray.push(data)})
      }))
    }
    
    function mainFunction() {
      var c = 1;
      $.when.apply($, $.map(AnotherMultiDimensionalArray, function(array) {
         return functionThatLoops(array,c);
      })
      .then(function() {
        console.log(myArray)
      })
    }`

Comment: The issue is `for..in` loops do not wait for jQuery promise returned by `$.get()`.